# Clarification of a point in the proof of $||| A|||\leq \rho(A)+\epsilon$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, spectral-radius

I want to prove that given $A\in \cal{M}_n$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists a matrix norm $||| \cdot |||$ such that
$$||| A|||\leq \rho(A)+\epsilon$$
where $\rho(A)$ si the spectral radius of $A$.

In the proof that I have seen it is shown that $|||A|||= \rho(A)+\epsilon$.

My question (maybe trivial sorry) is: I should prove the relation with $\leq$, so I could simply say that if I take an $\epsilon_1\geq \epsilon$ and then
$$||| A|||\leq \rho(A)+\epsilon\leq \rho(A)+\epsilon_1$$
Do you think my idea to pass from $=$ to $\leq$ is right? I think the passage is trivial since it is not specified in the proof, but I can't understand.

Comment: You can also rescale the norm you already have (multiple by something smaller than 1)

Comment: @rubikscube09 I guess that $\||\cdot\||$ is an induced norm, otherwise the statement is trivial (by rescaling as you suggested).

Comment: OP: As you noted, if you can prove $=$, then $\leq$ is true since $a=b$ implies $a\leq b$. Going from $\leq$ to $=$ is a different story.

Comment: @Surb ah ok so I can stop the proof at $=$ since $|||A|||=\rho(A)+\epsilon\implies |||A|||\leq\rho(A)+\epsilon$?